# How to filter lookup columns (which also contain lookup columns) in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have several SharePoint lists: `booking calendar`, `hot desks` and `location`.

The calendar has `hot desk` as a lookup column (linked to the hot desks list). The `hot desks` list also has a lookup column (linking to the `locations` list).

When I add a calendar item I have set up a workflow task to retrieve the location from the `hot desks` list (based on which hot desk was chosen) and populate the location field in the calendar.

That works fine, but I want to limit the list to those in a particular location (which is the filter in the calendar), so hot desks in other locations don't show - this is due to the fact there will be a 'hot desk 1' in more than one location.

Alternatively, is it possible to display the location in the dropdown when adding an item (i.e. `Hot Desk 1 (Location Name)` rather than `Hot Desk 1`. How can I do that (if possible without having to write C# code (i.e. just using SharePoint Designer))?

**Edit:**
If code has to be written, how do you filter the list before the form is shown to the user (i.e. is there an event fired, e.g. 'OnFormShow', 'OnListShow' or similar)?

**Edit 2:**
Cascading fields, while useful, are not quite what I am looking for as the add/edit form is opened from a calendar which is already filtered, and I only want to show the hot desks appropriate for that calendar view.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of cascading lookup field for that. We have a product for that called Connected Field. Find out more [here](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=ConnectedFields2007)
Download the trial version and see if it fits your needs

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for and not at a stage to invest in third party components

Comment: You can get the solution from Codeplex in that case, a bit more complicated to install and run, but still, no cost http://cascddlistwithfilter.codeplex.com/